# Set up kenlm for Windows

Tags: language-model, kenlm, make-scorer

The official [website](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/) makes it pretty clear that there is no support for `kenlm` in Windows. There is a Windows tag at the [github repository](https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/releases/tag/windows) but it seems to be maintained by few random contributors then and there.

How to set up kenlm for Windows then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Ubuntu in Windows through Windows Subsystem for Linux

1. [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) WSL for Windows
2. From your ubuntu bash navigate to the folder where you want to do the setup. You can access the Windows file system from the `/mnt/c/` folder, which you can find at the root directory.
3. From there simply follow the [official instructions](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/), that is clone the git repo, and run `cmake ..` & `make -j2` in order to build the project (after first making the necessary installations in your Ubuntu system).

Obviously, you must train the models or [scorers](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.3/Scorer.html) using the Linux bash. You can also use these models from Windows using the kenlm python [library](https://pypi.org/project/kenlm/).

E.g.

The two steps to build a scorer for the `deepspeech-model` as described [here](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.3/Scorer.html) should be executed from your Ubuntu system. But after you have the scorer you should be able to run the command

`deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm --scorer kenlm.scorer --audio audio.wav`

from Windows. However, once you have WSL there's no need to do this work from Windows. Things will work nicely @your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

The new [DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook) also includes instructions for setting up a Docker image and running training from within a Docker container. If you have Docker on Windows, this might be another solution.

The information for building a new Scorer is [still in a PR](https://github.com/mozilla/deepspeech-playbook/pull/14), but may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and solved it by building kenlm wheel from Cygwin terminal as home page advices (`pip wheel pypi-kenlm`).

I've also uploaded wheel to pypi called kenlm-cygwin, but it's only python3.7.